# cohomology ring of configuration spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, configuration-spaces

In the paper *configuration spaces: applications to Gelfand-Fuks cohomology*, by F. Cohen and L. Taylor, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 1978, theorem 1, I did not find the proof. What method did the author use to obtain Theorem 1?

Theorem 1:

Let $M=R^n\times V$, $V$ connected, $M$ a manifold of dimension $m$. How to obtain the  cohomology ring $H^*(F(M,k);\mathbb{F})$, where $F(M,k)$ is the ordered configuration space, $\mathbb{F}$ is a field?

**Where could I find the proof?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the proof is [published in Geometric Applications of Homotopy Theory I.](http://www.dropbox.com/s/w5iqazs0if3300e/CohenTaylor.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @AlexSuciu Fixed now, sorry

Comment: Dear Prpf. Igor, the paper *Computations of Gelfand-Fuks cohomomogy, ......*, in Geometric Applications of Homotopy Theory I. F. Cohen and L. Taylor, requires the coefficients to be a field of characteristic zero  most of the time. Is the Theorem 1 in the question derived from Section 2, Theorem 2.1, Remark 2.2 of the paper *Computations of Gelfand-Fuks cohomomogy, ......*, in Geometric Applications of Homotopy Theory I?